# UIButton of UITableViewCell disappear on scroll

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I Have a problem with my custom `UItableViewCell`. It's seems that all `UIButton` of `UITableViewCell` **disappear** on **scroll**. Specilay on my 25 cell. Any one have any idea ?

**any help would be appreciated :)**

[image]

***That some code :***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString*  cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    Cell * __strong cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if (!cell){
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    InfoObject __weak *obj = [_pos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [cell configCell];

    cell.id = obj.id;

    {// EVENT ON BUTTON
        [cell.checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btnPaymentState addTarget:self action:@selector(changePaymentState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }


    {// SET BUTTON CHECKBOX
        cell.checkbox.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_BLACK_UNCHECKBOX] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_BLACK_CHECKBOX] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cell.checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_BLACK_CHECKBOX] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }

    {// SET BUTTON PAYMENT STATE
        cell.btnPaymentState.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.btnPaymentState setImage:[self getImageAssociateWithName:obj.stringPaymentState] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.btnPaymentState setImage:[self getImageAssociateWithName:obj.stringPaymentState] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cell.btnPaymentState setImage:[self getImageAssociateWithName:obj.stringPaymentState] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    [self SetSelectedBackgroundColorSelectedForFolderCellAtRow:indexPath.row
                                                              :obj.selected Cell: cell];
    [cell.checkbox setSelected:obj.selected];
    [self setCellColorTextOfObjectPrepare:cell withObj:obj];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a cell reuse issue. Post code please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS UITableView Cell loads incorrectly after scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614845/ios-uitableview-cell-loads-incorrectly-after-scroll)

Comment: @vincent-g i add some code so what do you think ?

Comment: not much, Interface Builder I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem. The problem is that i was using **Tag** for my `UIButton` and the `identifier` was the **same** **number** **tag** of another **UIView** so when i was removing my `UIView` the `UIButton` disappear also. Thanks all for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove   if (!cell)

And you're good to go.